# Create a new array from existing array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a problem in creating a new array based on existing array.I have the following array and I want to match elements 'id' with 'parent' element. If the value is same then I want to create another array where the child elements will be under parent element.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 66
            [parent] => 26

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 47
            [parent] => 26

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 48           
            [parent] => 66

        )
```

I want it to be

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 66
                [parent] => 26

            ) 
             [0] => Array 
             (  

                      [id] => 48
                      [parent] => 66


             )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 47
                [parent] => 26

            )
```

I am stuck with the following code.I have got the values but I don't know how to match with another element in a array.

```
foreach($firstlevel_results as $k => $v)
{
     echo $v['id']."==".$v['parent']."==".$v['grandparent']."<br>";
}
```

Please suggest if there is any possible way.

Comment: That hardly justifies as trying to do it for yourself! **This is not a free coding site** Plese read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I am still trying with it and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Despite it seems long code it is easy. Basically, the idea should be it:

```
$my_array = Array(
    Array ('id' => 66, 'parent' => 26, 'grandparent' => 18), 
    Array ('id' => 23, 'parent' => 66, 'grandparent' => 57),
    Array ('id' => 47, 'parent' => 26, 'grandparent' => 18),
    Array ('id' => 48, 'parent' => 66, 'grandparent' => 26),
    Array ('id' => 11, 'parent' => 66, 'grandparent' => 89),
    Array ('id' => 200, 'parent' => 98, 'grandparent' => 26) 
);

function merge($target_id, $target_array) {
    #1) Find subarray with ID == $target_id
    $new = array();
    # fast path (better than array_filter)
    foreach ($target_array as $key => $sub_array) {
        #find array with id == $target_id
        if ($sub_array['id'] === $target_id) {
            # first index will be super group
            $new[0] = array($sub_array);
            # removing it...
            unset($target_array[$key]);
            # it's not need continue anymore...
            break;
        }
    }

    # 2)  and now gonna compare ids with targert_id
    foreach ($target_array as $index => $sub_array) {

        if ($sub_array['parent'] == $target_id) {
            # index 0 is the super group as said early...
            array_push($new[0], $sub_array);

        } else {
            # only push but not groups
            array_push($new, $sub_array);
        }
    }

    return $new;
}


print_r(merge(66, $my_array));
```

*Of course, there are points in this code that could be improved, but that's the idea.*

Comment: Thanks a lot @felip.Almost close. Only one thing if it is possible to put the id- 23,48,11 under id 66.Now they all are under same level.

Comment: There is one more problem that is I can't pass 66 inside a function.It needs to be calculated within a single loop.But the idea is great.I will try again.Thanks.

Comment: @Raj Yes, But the keys will be overwritten. The function named "merge" joins matched arrays by matched  in first index. I think it's best approach.

Comment: @Raj, Oh, I see... But it is same idea: if $newest_array["parent"] === $existent_array["id"], just merge it or adpat with above code. ;)